# Is there any Single-Sign-On(SSO) or CAS open source project using asp.net c#?

Tags: asp.net

I want to develop a Single-Sign-On(SSO) or centralized authentication server (CAS) project for SSO between asp.net, php and java.

Is there any Single-Sign-On(SSO) or centralized authentication server (CAS) open source project using asp.net c# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for something simple, you might consider an OpenID implementation. Since it's all HTTP request based authentication, ASP.NET, PHP and Java will have no problems working and you won't have to worry about creating and maintaining the credentials store, as that's all handled for you.

You can write the code yourself (check out [openid.net](http://openid.net)) or you can use something like [rpxnow.com](http://www.rpxnow.com), which is a 'wrapper service', to help you get started.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. But the third-party SSO such as openid is not allowed to use in our app. And I have to implement a sso by myself.